# Automatic in page gallery wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload, gallery

I'm looking for a simple image gallery for a client of mine.

I need to have the ability to upload multiple images from within a post or page and have the images automatically added to the page, and styled.

I was able to fine this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-image-4

Which sounds similar to what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Does anyone know how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out.

Just need to add this to functions.php

```
<?php
function postimage($size=medium,$num=1,$lighbox=1) {
    if ( $images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => $num,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
    {
        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $attachmenturl=wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
            $attachmentimage=wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, $size );
            $img_title = $image->post_title;
            $img_desc = $image->post_excerpt;
            if ($size != "full"){
                echo '<a href="'.$attachmenturl.'" rel="lightbox" title="'.$img_desc.'">'.$attachmentimage.'</a>'.$img_title.'';
            } else {
                echo '<img src="'.$attachmenturl.'">';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Image";
    }
}
?>
```

Then add this to the post page (in my case single.php)

```
<?php postimage('thumbnail'); ?>
```

Now any images uploaded in a particular post are automatically added.

Answer (score 0):

try nextgen gallery :) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: I've used this plugin before. It works great as an image gallery but, I need to be able to upload the images while directly editing a page/post.